# How would Tx/Rx handle maxiumum values causing overflow in Linux platform?

Tags: linux, networking

I have a Linux device sending data to remote Cloud services every 1 minute in 7 / 24 environment. To ensure reliability of sending data crossing Internet, not beholding internal kernel buffer, I need to monitor following statistics which I believe the RX / TX represents true numbers of packages coming / going out interfaces, right? If it is correct, what are following maximum numbers, uint32 or uint64? How will it handle when it reaches the maximum number to cause the overflow?

cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes

cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_packets

cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_packets

cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes

Thank you very much.

Kind regards,

jupiter

Answer (score 1):

> To ensure reliability of sending data crossing Internet, not beholding internal kernel buffer, I need to monitor following statistics which I believe the RX / TX represents true numbers of packages coming / going out interfaces, right?

That's a strange and silly way to monitor it.

First of all, if you use TCP/IP you can assume that transmission is reliable. E.g. you'll get a connection failure of some sort, that you can log in your application, if the transmission times out or connection fails. This will provide more accurate information than a mere packet counter.

Second, if you know that you send a message every minute, count the number of received messages. Not the number of packets, which would be layer 2, but the number of messages, which would be somewhere in the Layer 4 - Layer 7 roughly speaking. This will give you a better idea than counting packets.

If you count L2 packets, this includes replies to ping, broadcast traffic and all other kinds of traffic on the network.

Comment: Let's not discuss TCP, what you are talking about is basic TCP, the real implementation can be more complicated than you thought. Surrey you can setup in TCP low lever or in application to get an acknowledgement response for every Tx, we have reasons not doing the basic way, again, that is not the discussion for the topic. Let's stick on topic if you could help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Then do it in the protocol. Counting bytes is *not* verifying that messages is transmitted at L4. For the literal question asked, the answer is *trivially* googleable: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/statistics.html

Comment: To put it differently: There's a reason protocols such as MQTT do a real acknowledgement of messages (if desired), and doesn't rely on bytes transmitted on the wire. Bytes on the wire tells you *nothing*. It's more or less noise - especially for small messages.

Comment: Thanks vidarlo for the link, so bad that is not the number of packages pump out of device, we cannot use it. The reason we are so stingy for each bytes because the device has another interface 4G LTE, when it is connected by 4G, every byte costs in deployment of 10 thousands of devices

Comment: The link describes the data. It's uint64.

Comment: In addition, your question is essentially a X-Y-problem. What you really want to do is count bytes - but you ask about something entirely different...